# How to create private class member in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, class, powershell-5.0

I found out powershell have classes and I'm trying to use private class member. 
I know there is hidden class member but i need to use private for my project.
How can i create private class member in PowerShell?

Comment: This might be helpful. https://xainey.github.io/2016/powershell-classes-and-concepts/

Answer (score 7):

**You *cannot* create *private* members** in PowerShell (v5+) [custom classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes).

**A *hidden* member - declared with keyword `hidden` - is the closest *approximation*.**

A `hidden` member:

- is by default *not* listed when you inspect an instance of the class with `Get-Member`; use the 
  `-Force` switch to include them.
- is *not* auto-completed when you use tab completion.
- is *not* shown in default output formatting
- is *not* included when you pipe an instance to the following cmdlets:

  - `Select-Object`: using `-Property *` selects only all non-hidden properties, and hidden ones generally cannot be matched with *wildcard expression* - though you can select them by their full, literal name.
  - `ConvertTo-Csv`, `Export-Csv`
  - `ConvertTo-Xml` (rarely used)

**However, hidden members are *still publicly accessible*, if you access them directly**.

Hidden properties *are* included in the output from the following cmdlets :

- `Export-CliXml`: This makes sense, given that purpose of this cmdlet to create an as-faithful-as-possible serialized representation of its input objects.
- (As of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.5) `ConvertTo-Json`: This is surprising, given that `Select-Object`, and `ConvertTo-Csv` / `Export-Csv` and `ConvertTo-Xml` act differently.

  - See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9847).
  - As a workaround, you can first pipe to `Select-Object -Property *`, which implicitly excludes the hidden properties.

---

**Sample code**:

```
# Define class Foo with one hidden and one public property...
class Foo { hidden [string] $HiddenProp = 'hide me'; [string] $PublicProp = 'show me' }
# ... and create an instance stored in variable $foo.
$foo = [Foo]::new()
```

```
# Default formatting does *not* show .HiddenProp
# Similarly, typing $foo.Hi<tab> would *not* tab-complete to $foo.HiddenProp
PS> $foo

PublicProp
----------
show me
```

```
# However, if you refer to .HiddenProp directly,
# you can retrieve (or set) its value.
PS> $foo.HiddenProp
hide me
```

```
# .HiddenProp is not shown by default.
# Add -Force to include it.
PS> $foo | Get-Member -Type Properties


   TypeName: Foo

Name       MemberType Definition
----       ---------- ----------
PublicProp Property   string PublicProp {get;set;}
```

```
# .HiddenProp is not matched by the wildcard expression.
# Pass it in full, literally to force inclusion (Select-Object *, HiddenProp)
PS> $foo | Select-Object *Prop
```

```
# .HiddenProp is not serialized.
# You cannot force its inclusion.
# Ditto for Export-Csv
PS> $foo | ConvertTo-Csv
"PublicProp"
"show me"
```

```
# As of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.5:
# .HiddenProp IS unexpectedly serialized.
# You cannot force its *ex*clusion, except via
# an aux. `Select-Object *` call inserted before `ConvertTo-Json`
PS> $foo | ConvertTo-Json
{
  "HiddenProp": "hide me",
  "PublicProp": "show me"
}
```